# Write a method that gets two int arrays, that are of the same size and returns an array that is the sum of both

Tags: java, arrays, methods

My code below, and I can't understand what I have to use as parameter when calling a method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class addArrays {

    public static void main (String[]args) {
        int arr [] = new addArrays(int [] array1, int [] array2);
    }
    public static int[] addArrays(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the size of an array: ");
        int size = in.nextInt();
        int[] array1 = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            array1[size] = in.nextInt();
        }
        int[] array2 = new int[size];
        for (int j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
            array2[size] = in.nextInt();
        }
        int[] array3 = new int[size];
        for (int k = 0; k < array3.length; k++) {
            array3[size] = array1[size] + array2[size];
        }
        return array3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the assignment is for this method to read the arrays from the user? The word "gets" could just as easily be interpreted to mean "accepts as arguments". That would also make more sense, as the method would be doing just one thing and be reusable.

Comment: Yes, I asked my teacher and the answer was that I have to use user input to determine all the arrays.

Comment: Your code is non-sense. What do you really want to achieve ? Sum two arrays into one or populate an array based on user inputs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function addArrays takes two parameters (arr1 and arr2) but they are not used within the function. The arrays being added are initialized and populated within the function (array1 and array2).

I guess you should move the initialization and population of array1 and array2 into main(), and keep the addition of the two arrays separate, in the addArrays function. Then pass the array1 and array2 (populated from System.in) to the function.

You are also using the size variable instead of the index (i and j) to populate the arrays. These can all re-use the same index variable; it can be redefined or defined outside of the loops.

Pay attention to the names of variables and their visibility, especially when passing them into a function, and accepting them as function arguments.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class addArrays {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the size of an array: ");
        int size = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter numbers to populate array 1: ");
        int[] array1 = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            array1[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Please enter numbers to populate array 2: ");
        int[] array2 = new int[size];
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            array2[j] = in.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Thank you! The result is: ");
        int[] arr3 = addArrays(array1, array2);
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            System.out.println(arr3[j]);
        }
    }
    public static int[] addArrays(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        int size = arr1.length;
        int[] array3 = new int[size];
        for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
            array3[k] = arr1[k] + arr2[k];
        }
        return array3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! You saved me, I was stuck during all the day. So elegant and easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can assume they are the same size, so that makes things simpler.  Not really sure what you are trying to use scanner for, but the below function takes 2 arrays of the same size and returns one that is the sum of equivalent indices.

```
public static int[] addArrays(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    int size = arr1.length;
    int[] array1 = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        array1[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i];
    }
    return array1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Those two arrays should receive an input from user, so the user should set the size of all the arrays and fill an arrays, that make a sum later.

Comment: And also how I can use this method in main? What should I put into brackets ()? It should be something like         int arr[] =  addArrays(array1,array2); ? That's the thing that I can't get, sorry for stupid question.

Comment: yeah that is how you would call the method in main